# Is there any problem installing Ruby 1.9.1 when i already have installed ruby 1.8.7 running with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have ruby on rails installed on my Desktop
running

ruby 1.8.7

and

rails 2.3.8

i want to know is installing Ruby 1.9.1 version will mess up with my Rails apps?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).